# How to use mod_assign_save_grade?

Tags: web-services, moodle

I'm trying to use mod_assign_save_grade with : **https:/[my-root]/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=[token]&wsfunction=mod_assign_save_grade&moodlewsrestformat=json&assignmentid=4&userid =45&grade =15&attemptnumber =-1&addattempt =0&workflowstate =graded&applytoall =1**

but the output came with

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected"
}
```

any ideas to use it correctly

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are blank spaces before `=` in several places. I copied your request, (of course, with actual server name, token and parameter values), removed blanks and it works correctly. When I insert blank space anywhere, the message that you posted appears.